# this line of code makes the program unreactive to the restart function

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I try to write a program in python that lets the user to put a bet on one of the turtles and after the race tells him if he was correct or not.
I want to let the user choose if he wants to restart the race by clicking 'r' - ( i used the turtle.onkey method) and it worked fine until I put this line of code:
bet = screen.textinput("Choose your bet", "Enter blue or green: ").
now the program lets the user choose his bet like I wanted but then it wont react when 'r' is pressed..
I want to clarify that after the textinput line of code the program won't react to any of the .onkey methods.
anyone has idea why it happens?

THE CODE:

```
import turtle
import random
import ctypes

speed = random.randint(0, 2)

myTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
myTurtle2 = turtle.Turtle()
screen = turtle.Screen()
def up():
    myTurtle.setheading(90)
    myTurtle.forward(10)

def down():
    myTurtle.setheading(270)
    myTurtle.forward(10)

def left():
    myTurtle.setheading(180)
    myTurtle.forward(10)

def right():
    myTurtle.setheading(0)
    myTurtle.forward(10)

def up2():
    myTurtle2.setheading(90)
    myTurtle2.forward(10)

def down2():
    myTurtle2.setheading(270)
    myTurtle2.forward(10)

def left2():
    myTurtle2.setheading(180)
    myTurtle2.forward(10)

def right2():
    myTurtle2.setheading(0)
    myTurtle2.forward(10)

def restart():
    myTurtle.setposition(400, -300)
    myTurtle.setheading(90)
    myTurtle2.setposition(-400, -300)
    myTurtle2.setheading(90)
    speed = random.randint(0, 2)
    bet = screen.textinput("Choose your bet", "Enter blue or green: ")
    while myTurtle.ycor() < 300 and myTurtle2.ycor() < 300:
        if speed == 1:
            up()
        elif speed == 2:
            up2()
        speed = random.randint(0, 2)
    if myTurtle.ycor() == 300:
        if bet == "blue":
            ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Blue is the winner", "You win!", 0x00010000)
        else:
            ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Blue is the winner", "You lost", 0x00010000)
    else:
        if bet == "green":
            ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Green is the winner", "You win!", 0x00010000)
        else:
            ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Green is the winner", "You lost", 0x00010000)

screen.title("Turtle race")
turtle.listen()
myTurtle.shape("turtle")
myTurtle2.shape("turtle")
myTurtle.setposition(400,-300)
myTurtle.setheading(90)
myTurtle2.setposition(-400,-300)
myTurtle2.setheading(90)
myTurtle.dot(10, "blue")
myTurtle2.dot(10, "green")
myTurtle.pencolor("blue")
myTurtle2.pencolor("green")

myTurtle.speed(0)
myTurtle2.speed(0)
bet = screen.textinput("Choose your bet", "Enter blue or green: ")
while myTurtle.ycor() < 300 and myTurtle2.ycor() < 300:
    if speed == 1:
        up()
    elif speed == 2:
        up2()
    speed = random.randint(0, 2)

if myTurtle.ycor() == 300:
    if bet == "blue":
        ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Blue is the winner", "You win!", 0x00010000)
    else:
        ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Blue is the winner", "You lost", 0x00010000)
else:
    if bet == "green":
        ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Green is the winner", "You win!", 0x00010000)
    else:
        ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Green is the winner", "You lost", 0x00010000)



turtle.onkey(up, 'Up')
turtle.onkey(down, 'Down')
turtle.onkey(left, 'Left')
turtle.onkey(right, 'Right')

turtle.onkey(restart, 'r')

turtle.onkey(up2, 'w')
turtle.onkey(down2, 's')
turtle.onkey(left2, 'a')
turtle.onkey(right2, 'd')
turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: as for me `textinput` has to react on all keys so it may remove all `onkey`. Did you try to assing again `onkey` after `textinput` ?

Comment: there can be other problem - `while`-loop which runs all time and it blocks `mainloop()` which gets key/mouse events from system and check if you clicked `r` and executes assigned function. It may need [ontimer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.ontimer) instead of `while` to repeat function periodically and not block `mainloop()`

Comment: see doc for [key](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.onkeyrelease) - it needs `listen()` after `onkey()` to access keys from system.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that `onkey` needs focus on main window to get keys from system but when you execute `textinput` then this focus is lost and it needs `screen.listen()` again.

---

Minimal working code.

Because you repeate some code inside `restart()` and outside `restart()` so I run `restart()` instead of external code.

Because I don't use `Windows` so I used `tkinter.messagebox` to display messages. `turtle` already uses `tkinter` to display main window with canvas and `textinput`.

```
import turtle
import random
#import tkinter  as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

# functions ---

def up():
    myTurtle.setheading(90)
    myTurtle.forward(10)

def down():
    myTurtle.setheading(270)
    myTurtle.forward(10)

def left():
    myTurtle.setheading(180)
    myTurtle.forward(10)

def right():
    myTurtle.setheading(0)
    myTurtle.forward(10)

def up2():
    myTurtle2.setheading(90)
    myTurtle2.forward(10)

def down2():
    myTurtle2.setheading(270)
    myTurtle2.forward(10)

def left2():
    myTurtle2.setheading(180)
    myTurtle2.forward(10)

def right2():
    myTurtle2.setheading(0)
    myTurtle2.forward(10)

def restart():
    myTurtle.setposition(400, -300)
    myTurtle.setheading(90)
    myTurtle2.setposition(-400, -300)
    myTurtle2.setheading(90)
    
    speed = random.randint(0, 2)
    bet = screen.textinput("Choose your bet", "Enter blue or green: ")

    screen.listen()  # <--- set focus on main window after `textinput`
    
    while myTurtle.ycor() < 300 and myTurtle2.ycor() < 300:
        if speed == 1:
            up()
        elif speed == 2:
            up2()
        speed = random.randint(0, 2)

    if myTurtle.ycor() == 300:
        if bet == "blue":
            messagebox.showinfo("Result", "Blue is the winner\n\nYou win!")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Result", "Blue is the winner\n\nYou lost")
    else:
        if bet == "green":
            messagebox.showinfo("Result", "Green is the winner\n\nYou win!")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Result", "Green is the winner\n\nYou lost")
    
# --- main ---

speed = random.randint(0, 2)

myTurtle  = turtle.Turtle()
myTurtle2 = turtle.Turtle()

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.title("Turtle race")

myTurtle.shape("turtle")
myTurtle2.shape("turtle")

turtle.onkey(up, 'Up')
turtle.onkey(down, 'Down')
turtle.onkey(left, 'Left')
turtle.onkey(right, 'Right')

turtle.onkey(restart, 'r')

turtle.onkey(up2, 'w')
turtle.onkey(down2, 's')
turtle.onkey(left2, 'a')
turtle.onkey(right2, 'd')

restart()

turtle.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Reduced code - I keep turtles on list and later I can use `myTurtles[number]` and I can use one function `up(number)` instead two functions `up()` and `up2()`

```
import turtle
import random
from tkinter import messagebox

# functions ---

def up(number):
    myTurtles[number].setheading(90)
    myTurtles[number].forward(10)

def down(number):
    myTurtles[number].setheading(270)
    myTurtles[number].forward(10)

def left(number):
    myTurtles[number].setheading(180)
    myTurtles[number].forward(10)

def right(number):
    myTurtles[number].setheading(0)
    myTurtles[number].forward(10)

def restart():
   
    myTurtles[0].setposition(400, -300)
    myTurtles[0].setheading(90)
    myTurtles[1].setposition(-400, -300)
    myTurtles[1].setheading(90)
    
    bet = screen.textinput("Choose your bet", "Enter blue or green: ")
    screen.listen()
    
    speed = random.randint(0, 2)
    while myTurtles[0].ycor() < 300 and myTurtles[0].ycor() < 300:
        if speed < 2: # randint(0, 2) can gives 0, 1, 2  
            up(speed)
        speed = random.randint(0, 2)

    if myTurtles[0].ycor() == 300:
        if bet == "blue":
            messagebox.showinfo("Result", "Blue is the winner\n\nYou win!")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Result", "Blue is the winner\n\nYou lost")
    else:
        if bet == "green":
            messagebox.showinfo("Result", "Green is the winner\n\nYou win!")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Result", "Green is the winner\n\nYou lost")
    
# --- main ---

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.title("Turtle race")

myTurtles = [
    turtle.Turtle(),
    turtle.Turtle(),
]    

myTurtles[0].shape("turtle")
myTurtles[1].shape("turtle")

turtle.onkey(lambda: up(0),    'Up')
turtle.onkey(lambda: down(0),  'Down')
turtle.onkey(lambda: left(0),  'Left')
turtle.onkey(lambda: right(0), 'Right')

turtle.onkey(lambda: up(1),    'w')
turtle.onkey(lambda: down(1),  's')
turtle.onkey(lambda: left(1),  'a')
turtle.onkey(lambda: right(1), 'd')

turtle.onkey(restart, 'r')

restart()

turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: I actually tried to findout how to make a list of turtles as well:) thx! I didnt understand though why you used lambda in the .onkey methods

Comment: `onkey` needs function's name without `()` and arguments - it is called "callback". I use `lambda` to put function with `()` and arguments. Normally I would have to create function `def up0(): up(0)` or `up0 = lambda:up(0)` and then use `onkey(up0, 'Up')`